# Git cherry-pick ,can't find "<<<<<HEAD" marker in conflict files

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I met a problem when I cherry-pick a commit on my branch. Below is what I did:

```
$ git cherry-pick  50658
$ git status
```

Error messages:

```
Not currently on any branch.
You are currently cherry-picking commit 5065872.
  (fix conflicts and run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:      drivers/media/dvb-core/dvb_frontend.c
```

But when I input **git diff**. It tells below :

```
diff --cc drivers/media/dvb-core/dvb_frontend.c
index 7023d5f,72fc718..0000000
--- a/drivers/media/dvb-core/dvb_frontend.c
+++ b/drivers/media/dvb-core/dvb_frontend.c
```

I didn't find any conflict massage, as `<<<<<<HEAD` in `dvb_frontend.c` files. Why it tells conflicts exiting ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the middle of a conflict; you should not use `git diff`; you should use any editor you like to resolve the conflicts, then

```
git add <filename>
```

at that moment you can use

```
git diff --cached
```

to see what your final commit will actually look like. When that is ok for you; you can use

```
git cherry-pick --continue
```

to finalize the commit you are cherry-picking.

Comment: I used vim command,but found no HEAD>>>>> marker. I don't know why.

Comment: the markers just start with `<<<<<` , `=====` and `>>>>>`... just search for that

Comment: did you retry from the start? It's hard to believe you are still cherry-picking after 5 days. To make sure: `git cherry-pick --abort` to abort any cherry-pick that is happening. Make sure `git status` says everything is ok. then retry your `git cherry-pick <sha-of-commit>` and if any conflict arises just open up the conflicting file and search for the `<<<<<` markers

Comment: I have this same issue. Are you using VS Code?